# empty field validation still fires if the fields are not empty in Selenium + Specflow

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow, pageobjects

When I fill the fields with values and submit, empty field validation still fires randomly and not everytime. As you can see in the image, the fields are non empty , still validations are fired.

I have noticed, usually selenium takes time to enter details, but in my case, as soon as the page loads, it quickly starts filling the fields speedily. Its unusually fast.

I am using Selenium , specflow framework and page object pattern and page factory.

My code for entering the text field is below :

```
public static void FillTextBox(IWebElement webElement,string value)
        {
            webElement.Click();
            webElement.Clear();
            webElement.SendKeys(value);
        }
```

[image]

Please help me with this.

Comment: Find out from your developer what events are triggering the validation. Otherwise we could be here for a long time guessing.

Comment: One of it is Blur event.

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the definition of the `onBlur` event, you will find:

> The onblur event occurs when an object loses focus.

So you have to shift focus to another element **after** you fill in each text box.

```
public static void FillTextBox(IWebElement textField, string value, IWebElement otherElement) {

    textField.SendKeys(value);
    otherElement.Click();    // this will have to be some other element on your page
}
```

Comment: But you can see i am already clicking on elenment first and then filling the values. so whats the difference ?